# What means put preprocessor in std::string?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

When I read **leela-zero** source code, I don't understand putting preprocessor in `std::string`. In my experiments with **Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019**, the code didn't work.

[leela-zero code](https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero/blob/next/src/OpenCL.cpp) 69~71line

source code:

```
const std::string sourceCode_common =
#include <stdio.h>
;
```

error code:

```
E0029 expected an expression
```

Comment: This is about OpenCL code. What are you trying to achieve? They put code, which has to be compiled at runtime into a std::string

Comment: The actual code includes `"common.opencl"`. Check out the contents of that. It's just pasting the contents of the header into the string. Note the `R"(` on line 16.

Comment: The code at lines 69-71 of your cited source is not the same as the code you have posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
static const std::string sourceCode_convolve1 =
    #include "kernels/convolve1.opencl"
;
```

That's how `#include` works. It literally includes (copy-pastes) the content of a file. If this file happens to be a valid string literal this works (e.g. The file could be something like `"content...."` as long as it's content is valid string literal).

Answer (score 0):

When you put an `#include <whatever>` in your code, the compiler copy and paste the entire content of the file in the file, if you go and check the file that's included, you can see that the entire file (without the preprocesor directives) is a valid string literal.

https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero/blob/next/src/kernels/common.opencl

`R"(` is a start of a verbatim string.